# Rewrite Portion of URL Only

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a URL so that `this-area-profile-` will change to `area-profile-`, with everything after "profile-" matching what was in the original URL:

`http://example.com/a-directory/this-area-profile-everything-after-profile-`

`http://example.com/a-directory/area-profile-everything-after-profile-`

The below is my latest of numerous attempts, based on what I have read here and on other websites:

```
RewriteRule ^a-directory/area-profile-(.+)$ /a-directory/this-area-profile-$1 [R=301,L]
```

The other answers talk about changing or removing a directory, but I want to rename a portion of the URL.

Comment: Are you having any issues with your current solution?

Comment: yes, that one does not work, that is, the example I wrote above...

Comment: Have you tried `.*` rather than `.+` ?

Comment: I believe so but will try again for that exact line. Will have to reply tomorrow, thanks

Comment: I had a look and the only difference with what you have and what I thought the answer should be is that. Good luck.

Comment: @Tony Your current rule is the opposite of what you want, right now your rule is telling the browser to redirect `area-profile-rest` to `this-area-profile-rest` or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thank you, I reversed it now

Answer (score 0):

I know my english is bad, but I understand the opposite from your explanation:

```
RewriteRule ^a-directory/this-area-profile-(.+)$ /a-directory/area-profile-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I understood your English fine thank you, I have reversed the line as Prix and you stated and changed `(.+)` to `(.*)`. It still does not work but believe this is the correct direction. I think there might be some underlying cause that I will have to look at. Thanks much.